# DM mentioned user in discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to dm a mentioned user in discord.

I need something like

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    # ...

client = MyClient()
client.run("Token")
```

not discord.ext because it would ruin my code.

I tried:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith("/trade"):
    mention = message.author.mention
    await client.send(mention, message.author + " will mit dir traden!")
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need `message.author.send`

Comment: @mkrieger1 bcs is because and it woukd ruin my code because there would be 2 client things, and i have so many functions and then i would have to recreate them.

Comment: @mousetail i dont want to dm the author, i want to dm the mentioned user

Comment: ok, so why are you using `client` intead of the mentioned user? Use `message.mentions[0]`

Comment: @mousetail i wanted to say that im not very got at discord.py but, i saw an other stackoverflow question that answered something almost like my question and i did it, im done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend using `/` as a prefix due to the potential confusion of the built in  slash commands (coming in d.py 2.0 for bots).

You probably are better using ext.commands eventually though as you can type hint the user much easier within the command signature.
e.g.

```py
@commands.command()
async def trade(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    # Code here
    await member.send("message")
```

In your example though you will want to use message.mentions to get a list of users mentioned in the message. If you want just the first mention then you can use the index 0  `message.mentions[0]`

```py
mentioned_member = message.mentions[0]
await mentioned_member.send("Message")
```